# Rescale heatmap

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, heatmap

I generated a heatmap using geom_tile of the ggplot package:

```
plot<-ggplot(melted_Activities, aes(x=X1, y=value, group=X2)) + geom_area(position='identity', aes(fill=X2), alpha=0) + geom_line(aes(color=X2)) + labs(x="Time (hours)", y="Value(kW_Raw_data)", title="")+theme_bw() 
plot+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c( "04:00","05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00","13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00"), expand = c(0,0)) +scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

Now I want to I reduce the scale of my heatmap?Is this to do with standardisation?

How do I implement this??

The `melted_Activities` data frame consists of 3 columns :

```
  X1(Time): 04:00-03:35
    X2(Activities): 44
    value =[0-136480]
```

Data:

```
dput(head(melted_Activities, 10))
structure(list(X1 = structure(25:34, .Label = c("00:00", "00:10", 
"00:20", "00:30", "00:40", "00:50", "01:00", "01:10", "01:20", 
"01:30", "01:40", "01:50", "02:00", "02:10", "02:20", "02:30", 
"02:40", "02:50", "03:00", "03:10", "03:20", "03:30", "03:40", 
"03:50", "04:00", "04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", "04:50", 
"05:00", "05:10", "05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50", "06:00", 
"06:10", "06:20", "06:30", "06:40", "06:50", "07:00", "07:10", 
"07:20", "07:30", "07:40", "07:50", "08:00", "08:10", "08:20", 
"08:30", "08:40", "08:50", "09:00", "09:10", "09:20", "09:30", 
"09:40", "09:50", "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", "10:40", 
"10:50", "11:00", "11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", "11:50", 
"12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", "13:00", 
"13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", "14:10", 
"14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50", "15:00", "15:10", "15:20", 
"15:30", "15:40", "15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", "16:30", 
"16:40", "16:50", "17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", "17:40", 
"17:50", "18:00", "18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", "18:50", 
"19:00", "19:10", "19:20", "19:30", "19:40", "19:50", "20:00", 
"20:10", "20:20", "20:30", "20:40", "20:50", "21:00", "21:10", 
"21:20", "21:30", "21:40", "21:50", "22:00", "22:10", "22:20", 
"22:30", "22:40", "22:50", "23:00", "23:10", "23:20", "23:30", 
"23:40", "23:50"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), .Label = c("Activites related to employment", 
"Arts and hobbies", "Childcare of own household member", "Computing", 
"Construction and repairs", "Eating", "Employment", "Entertainment and culture", 
"Food management", "Free time study", "Gardening and pet care", 
"Help to an adult household member", "Hobbies, games and computing", 
"House and family care", "Household maintenance", "Household management", 
"Informal help to others", "Main job", "Making care for textiles", 
"Mass media", "Organisational work", "Other personal care", "Participatory activties", 
"PC Games", "Personal care", "Physical exercise", "Productive exercise", 
"Punctuating activity", "Radio and music", "Reading", "Resting", 
"School or University", "Second job", "Shopping and services", 
"Sleep", "Social care", "Social life", "Sport and outdoor activities", 
"Sportsrelated activities", "Study", "Travel and unspecified time use", 
"Travel by purpose", "Tv and video", "Volunteer work and meeting"
), class = "factor"), value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    value_scaled = structure(c(-0.326209785008489, -0.326209785008489, 
    -0.326209785008489, -0.326209785008489, -0.326209785008489, 
    -0.326209785008489, -0.326209785008489, -0.326209785008489, 
    -0.326209785008489, -0.326209785008489), .Dim = c(10L, 1L
    ))), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Normalize the value variable:

melted_Activities <- transform(melted_Activities, value = (melted_Activities$value - min(melted_Activities$value)) / (max(melted_Activities$value) - min(melted_Activities$value)))